# Load items while scrolling - Angular 4 and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to create a page with articles. I do not want to load all articles at once though (because there are a lot and they have images). I want to make something like Facebook or 9gag has. They have a system and when you scroll it will automatically append items.

Can anyone point me in the right direction how to challenge this?

Should I request the articles JSON all in once (from server) or should I request them when I scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load results as they are needed, the mechanism is generally called infinite scroll.

For angular4 you can look at https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll (haven't tried it myself but it looks like it will fit your needs)